# The word for a place no one has visited before?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a place where no one has visited or at least only a few people have visited before?

Comment: Is it only defined from the viewpoint of the incognizant?

Comment: Pristine?  Unspoiled?  Virgin?

Answer (score 6):

Unknown or unexplored territory is referred to as *[terra incognita](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/terra-incognita?q=terra%20incognita)*.

Comment: What if there are human inhabitants? Is it still terra incognita?

Comment: To those coming in from the outside, absolutely. ("Europeans, meet headhunters. Headhunters, European cuisine.")